# Getting all users in Moodle using the webservices

Tags: web-services, moodle

I'm developing a Java client to interact with Moodle. I want to get all the users registered within a Moodle installation.

I found the webservice function called `core_user_get_users` which returns a list with users.

When I call the service without any parameters I get a repsonse with a `invalid parameter` exception.

When I add a criteria parameter (`criteria[0][key]=id&criteria[0][value]=some_id`) it returns a single user with that specific `id`.

I can't seem to find what criteria to pass to the function to get the entire list with users registered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `email` criteria. If you have the value `%%` it will retrieve all registered users.

Comment: A similar but perhaps more intuitive and useful variant of this approach is to use the `deleted` field and the value `0`, that will return all users that have not been deleted.

Comment: @BartB It works but actually it is not intended to as the warning shows when you do so:    `"item": "deleted",
            "warningcode": "invalidfieldparameter",
            "message": "The search key 'deleted' is not supported, look at the web service documentation"`

Comment: @wp78de everything you do to get all users is a 'hack' because that's not what this API call is really for. The problem is, there is no API call for getting all users 

Comment: Actually everything seems to work as a search criteria, even if it does not exist (i.e. `idontevenexist` instead of `deleted`) 